# How do I round the corner of images in Chrome (and other webkit browsers)?

Tags: css, google-chrome

In Firefox if I put an image in an element and then use border-radius, Firefox clips the image and it looks great! Works the same way in IE9 (amazing!). In Chrome (or any webkit browser) the border is rounded but it doesn't clip the image and it looks horrible. What am I doing wrong?

```
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
```

[image: Image Example]

Comment: We need some HTML with this... Or, all the CSS?

Comment: Any reason you can't just add border radius on the `img` element, as well?  (I know it means more code, but that's what happens when doing cross browser sites)

Comment: Do you apply the rule to the img itself, or a parent element?

Comment: In this case I was putting it on the image itself and noticed the difference between FF and Chrome. I ended up fixing the problem by removing the padding as suggested below. Sucks there is no spec and it looks different in each browser . . . the life of a web developer!

Answer (score 3):

Put it into a `div`?
And style them seperately.

http://jsfiddle.net/Stijntjhe/bFECN/1/

Comment: Yeah, that certainly works! But it seems there must be another solution that doesn't mean adding a new elements to the dom.

Comment: I don't think there is one. It's just how Chrome handles the situation. And I think Chrome handles it right. Because if you say `border-radius`, it's not likely the complete element rounds... Only the border should.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the spec is defined well in this scenario, hence the two different results.

When you don't have padding, WebKit will clip the image based on the border radius.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/bFECN/5/

However there isn't anything in the spec that says that the padding must also be a part of the radius drawing.

Comment: I noticed that! I was playing around with styles in Chrome Dev Tools. That's what I changed for now. Still looking for and trying things out.

Comment: Nice picture choice by the way! Notice that the corners are missing the border! That's a problem for a :hover that changes the border color (and also, it looks strange if the image contrasts the border too much).

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted more than one year ago and webkit has the same problem with border radius support with images. So I solve this with a small trick, instead of use css borders, I change the method using double box-shadow. In your case should be something like this.

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 4px #bdbdbd;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 4px #bdbdbd;
box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 4px #bdbdbd;

border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
```